# specifying path attribute as http/https link in cloudfoundry manifest

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is it possible to provide path attribute as an http/https url link from where we download the respective precompiled jar/war in cloudfoundry manifest and how?

Comment: The documentation states that 'path' requires a directory, so it is not possible. But what you could do is simply curl the jar to the location defined in your manifest and afterwards invoke 'cf push'.

Answer (score 0):

The "path" flag and manifest attributes only take a local filepath.

The V3 CC API has been designed in a way to be open to future enhancements like a accepting a remote file path (so CC could download the app directly from there, as opposed to the indirect way of the work-around suggested in the comment to download it locally first and then have it uploaded again), but I don't believe there is any timeline for such feature yet.